# How can I stream my audio to my Sonos speakers?

Tags: audio, streaming

I would like to listen to good quality audio while watching a video, but my Sonos does not have a line in.

My idea is to stream it from the Raspberry Pi and listen to it on the Sonos by tuning in to a local radio station.

I don't mind the delay - I can adjust the synchronization in Kodi.

Comment: Which model are you talking about - is it bluetooth or wifi (or both - I don't know)?

Comment: @SlySven I'm interested in a solution depending exclusively on WIFI.

Comment: i am just about to do this one:
https://en.community.sonos.com/music-services-and-sources-228994/add-aux-to-sonos-using-raspberry-pi-6793268

Answer (score 4):

It took me weeks to get a workable solution and in the process I read hundreds of webpages with ideas, instructions and software to download.

Finally I was able to reject 90% of it and come up with a relatively simple solution.

### In summary:

**Kodi** -> **Alsa** -> **avconv** -> **ezstream** -> **Icecast2** -> **Sonos**

### The steps:

**Kodi**

I've only tried this with OSMC v2015.12-4 (Kodi 15.2)
There are two things to do within Kodi:

- Switch the audio output device
- Adjust the video/audio sync (this method has approx. 5,3 sec. delay)

**Alsa**

To be able to tap into the audio stream, the simplest thing is to install the loopback sound module under Alsa. Life is too short for PulseAudio…

**Avconv**

`avconv` (aka. ffmpeg) will capture the audio from the Alsa loopback, convert it to mp3 and send it to Ezstream.

**Ezstream**

Ezstream can take an mp3 file or stream and feed it to Icecast2.

**Icecast2**

To stream audio you can use Icecast2. It’s highly configurable, can take many sources and exposes a web interface.

**Sonos**

Your Sonos system will need to setup to play a local radio station (mp3 over http) from Icecast2.

---

For all the details, read my blog article with step-by-step instructions here:
http://jgivoni.tumblr.com/post/137612797027/streaming-the-audio-from-a-raspberry-pi-2-with

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Note that as written it comes very close to self promotion and or spam.

Comment: Reading: "*...Life is too short for PulseAudio…*" in your article made me smile - please write it up here! 8-)

Comment: @SteveRobillard I see your point and I expected some users to turn it down for those reasons. I just wanted to give people a chance to find this answer. However, I might improve the answer when I get a few minutes if it can help avoiding those nasty downvotes :-)

Comment: I followed the steps on the Tumblr post and got “ DBus error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown - The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files” when I restarted. And OSMC would not boot - it flashed a sad face. To get OSMC to boot correctly, I had to undo the configuration steps under the “Alsa Looback” section. I documented at https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/error-after-installing-icecast-2-ezstream-and-avconv-dbus-error-org-freedesktop-dbus-error-serviceunknown-the-name-org-freedesktop-upower-was-not-provided-by-any-service-files/86559 . Any suggestions?